# what is the correct way to make mocks when testing a method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I am new using mocks , specially **jMock** (for java). I've done some testing before but not with mock and I am wondering what is the correct way to make them.

For example, I have a service with the implementation.. so, I have this service test. At the server test I have my methods.

Lets say I have `methodA` on `serviceHelperTest` , and as part of `methodA` I have this

```
ArrayList someValues = serviceHelperImpl.otherMethod
```

So, as far as I know, I should mock this `serviceHelperImpl.othermethod`, because I don't really care if is good or not, it is supposed to return some values.

So, let's say I expect a `boolean` value, is it possible to do this?

```
public myMethodToTest(){
     mockery.checking(new Expectations() {
     {
                oneOf(serviceHelper).otherMethod();
                will(returnValue(true));


            }
        });


     Boolean myVar = serviceHelper.otherMethod();
     ...
}
```

I dont know if this is correct or not... any idea how mocks should be implemented on testing units?

Comment: your explanation is confusing. Where is methodA or serviceHelperImpl? can you show a full example

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking a practice question (how should mocking be used) or an implementation question (how do I use mocking in this situation). If the former, perhaps look at http://www.michaelminella.com/testing/the-concept-of-mocking.html. If the latter then you will need to ask a more specific question and accept that the answer will change depending on mocking framework.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about why are you trying to save the return value from `serviceHelper.otherMethod();` if the purpouse of this is to test `otherMethod` you should only call `serviceHelper.otherMethod();` without save the returned value in a variable. Remember that mock tests are to check the "state" of a function, not the result. If you want to check the result you should use xUnit tests.